# call to innerHTML contains a cross-site scripting (XSS)

Tags: javascript

Getting cross site scripting (XSS) issue in javascript file in veracode scan report.

It seems the issue is with innerHtml?

```
{
    var b = document.createElement("div");
    b.innerHTML = g.responseText;

    for(var d=null,b=b.childNodes,e=0,h=b.length;e<h;++e)
    {
        var p=b[e];

);
```

Comment: Can you please format your code to make it more readable? Also, what is your question exactly?

Comment: Yes... and? Are you asking how to fix it, or just why it's happening? I'm assuming `g.responseText` is the response from some kind of AJAX. Here, you're just outputting whatever the response is directly to the page, without sanitizing it, which means if the response contains script tags, any JS in it will just run without checking that it's safe. This is bad.

Comment: The code you have posted needs to be fixed, use the [edit] button to make changes to it

Answer (score 1):

In general, using `innerHTML` should be avoided unless you know *exactly* what you're doing.

I'm unfamiliar with Veracode, but I'd wager it's noticing that you're making a fetch request, then inserting data from the response *directly* into your page as *code*. It's sounding the alarm about this, as it should. Inserting XHR content directly as HTML is **dangerous**, as it could allow a malicious actor to execute code on your page in any of the following hypothetical scenarios:

- You don't control the endpoint you're querying.
  <sup>Always *assume* that third-party data is malicious and act to secure your site accordingly.</sup>
- You control the endpoint, but it becomes compromised.
  <sup>Envision the worst-case scenario, where a hacker breaks in and modifies the data you send to the client.</sup>
- The endpoint returns unsanitized user input.
  <sup>A user could name themselves `<script>alert(1);</script>` and cause an alert to appear.</sup>

In any of these cases, it's possible for someone to insert a script or other content into a response, which, *because you're using `innerHTML`*, will be executed as HTML in the context of the page. This is a textbook example of an XSS (cross-site scripting) vulnerability. Hackers can (*and very often do*) use exploits like this for malicious purposes, including stealing the passwords, session cookies, and payment information of your end users. You're being warned in your code because hackers could potentially do the same thing to you.

If you're returning HTML code from your endpoint, firstly, **don't**. Return the data you want to put inside the elements in JSON format, then construct the elements yourself on the client side using [`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) and [`Node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent). This will ensure that the data you return isn't interpreted as HTML code.

If you're retrieving static, non-HTML data from the endpoint, then you don't even need a workaround-- just switch `innerHTML` to `textContent` and you'll be on your way.